# Really, really basic cross compiling C programs

Tags: c, windows, macos

I have a (*really* basic) C program I can compile with GCC on my mac. No need for code, it `fseek`s, `fread`s, `fprintf`s and that's it (it makes use of `stdlib.h` and `stdio.h`).

Is there a way for me to compile a win32 binary on my Mac which would run on Windows XP?

I'm looking for a simple (under 15 minute) solution, if the answer is "find someone who has Visual Studio" then that's cool :)

Comment: Yes there is a way, using a cross compiler, although which one to use I can't help you with

Comment: I think it's possible to build MINGW for OSX, but if you don't want to do that you could run Windows in a virtual machine on your Mac and use whatever compiler you want inside that VM.

Comment: Find someone who has a Windows machine with a compiler. (There are more compilers for Windows than just VS, though!)

Comment: The non-15-minute answer is to get a cross-compiler. You can try `crosstool`, but it's some work to set up.

Comment: MinGW seems to do what you need check out this link - though I've never tried it myself but the question perked my interest! http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/66450/mingw-equivalent-for-osx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [MinGW port for Mac](http://crossgcc.rts-software.org/doku.php) for cross compilation.